# Prevent spaces in password

Tags: regex

After being advised that I should allow special characters in my password field, how can I allow them in my regular expression but not allow spaces?

I have tried:

```
 ((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[\S]{8,})
```

But you can still enter spaces.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest that you're going wrong by applying any kind of validation to password entry other than "it must be supplied and at least X characters" - why do you want to prevent someone who prefers to use pass-*phrases* from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

It's not anchored. Add anchors to your regex:

```
^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[\S]{8,})$
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/hX6gL8/4).

Comment: I can still type in 8 spaces and 1 alpha/uppercase/lowercase and it still validates.

Comment: @panthro [Does not seem so, what's your regex engine?](http://regex101.com/r/hX6gL8/5)

Comment: No idea. I'm writing a custom rule for: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html#predefined-patterns

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to use this:

```
^(?!\d+$)(?![a-zA-Z]+$)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$
```

**Password Format:**  letters + numbers ,length 8 above